# Is there any possible way to use require() instead of import in wdio latest?

Tags: require, webdriver-io

Is there any possible way to use require() instead of import in wdio latest?

facing issues when upgraded to latest webdriverIO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below if it is a page object you are trying to import

```html
//somePage.js
var somePage = function(){

  this.eleClick = async function(){
    //some code
  }

}

module.export = new somePage();



//test.js

const page = require("somePage.js");

async function test(){
  page.eleClick();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).